# how to redirect back to app login page after authentication in ionic capacitor project

Tags: deep-linking, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

i have recently switched to capacitor, my app uses sso login after login and getting token, it used to redirect back to app, but after using capacitor, i m getting the token but not getting redirected to the app.

below is the previous code that was working :
platform.ready().then(() => {

```
     this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.navChild, {
       '/form-list/:token': this.router.navigate(['login'])
     }).subscribe((match) => {
    
       console.log('Successfully routed', match.$args);
     }, (nomatch) => {
       console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
     });
}
```

after switching to capacitor and changing the code accordingly after going through all the documents, the new code is :

initializeApp() {

```
  App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('Successfully routed',data);
         
          const slug = data.url.split(".app").pop();
          if (slug) {
               this.router.navigate(['login']);
          }
         
      });
  });
```

}

Please help in getting this issue resolved, have already spend good amount of time in resolving this.
Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Without your routing code, can you confirm that the listener for `appUrlOpen` firing?

Comment: @johnborges yes the appUrlOpen is firing as i can see the console logs and it is also going inside if condition for slug